# interface circuit between amplifier and antenna

Tags: rf, antenna

What type of interface circuit is used between the final amplifier output and the antenna? I see a lot of circuits use a group of inductors and capacitors after the amplifier output to the antenna. For example what are these capacitors and inductors after the coupling capacitor up to the antenna

1- Are these just filters?

2- I also want to know about impedance matching. Do I need impedance matching for my simple wire antenna, at frequency of 433 MHz?

3- How I determine the values of these capacitors and inductors ?
[image]

Comment: Haven't seen a final amplifier *without* filters between the amplifying device and antenna. An example circuit would help clarify the context: some filters also include impedance-matching.

Comment: the inductors and capacitors also act as your impedance matching network

Comment: Agreeing with @glen_geek: without you actually showing the circuit you're considering, how should we answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most often you'll see a PI network, either CLC or LCL. The LCL provides DC blocking. But the CLC only needs one inductor. You can add a 4rth component to implement DC_blocking on either end of the PI; use a "large" cap.

The PI performs by resonating at your frequency of interest, or approximately, based on your antenna mag/phase properties.

If you caps are 10pF at PowerAmp and 30pF at Antenna, the voltage at Antenna will be 10/30 = 1/3 of the PowerAmp output RF voltage. In this CLC loop, the *same* current flows through each capacitor.

Comment: Mmmm interesting so this is the name of this circuit after the amplifier to antenna (pi circuit) , this is the answer that I am looking for .

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a matchbox, an impedance matching device.

[image]

A: Do I need it?
Q: It depends on the antenna impedance/type you have it and the amplifier output type/impedance. If you have a 50 ohm output, 50 ohm coax cable and quarter wavelength antenna 50 ohm, then you don't need the matchbox. Especially if you don't how how to tune it, you'd better use direct connection, because a small mismatch is better than total mismatch.